Transpose data from horizontal table to vertical calendar based on criteria
I have been trying to transpose data from Leave Register (horizontal form) to Monthly Calendar (vertical form), if a certain condition is matched.
My Leave Register table looks like following:
horizontal list
... and I would like to transpose data into following calendar if Enroll is matched:
vertical list
Many thanks in advance!

If two people are on leave on the same date, what should the "vertical list" look like?

What happened top Jane Eyre in your vertical list?

Thanks for helping me out rachel and P.b
In the vertical table, I would like to have one person data at a time.
For example, one enroll data will be manually put in the Cell A2; this should result into getting leave data returned into Column D correspondingly.
Thanks again.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A possible way to tackle this could be:
If your horizontal list is on Sheet1,
Your Enroll ID is on a new sheet, cell A2 and your date range on your sheet is a spill range C2# (for instance: =LET(y,2024,m,4,s,DATE(y,m,1),SEQUENCE(EDATE(s,1)-s,,s))), then this would spill the results for this specific ID:
=BYROW(C2#,LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(Sheet1!C2:C4,(Sheet1!D2:D4<=b)*(Sheet1!E2:E4>=b)*(Sheet1!A2:A4=A2)))))

For older Excel enter this formula using ctrl+shift+enter:
=TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$4<=C2)*(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$4>=C2)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4=$A$2)))

Thanks a lot! @P.b
Unfortunately the solution provided isn't functioning with my MS Office version 2019.
Is there any other way out?
Lots of thanks again!

@MoazAbdullah added a version to exclude BYROW. Use that in D2 and drag down.

Working super great !!! Many many thanks @P.b !
P.S. Have to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter after the formula to make it functional.

Thanks, added that to the answer. I tend to forget Excel required to have array functions to be entered that way to work in older versions.
